# Regarding BLE Multiple Peripheral Simulation

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

For one of my project I am looking for a way to do Multiple BLE Peripheral Simulation. I need the Peripheral will do Advertise only. No BLE Connect needed. I know Apps like LightBlue or BLE-Utility but that can do simulate only 1 Peripheral at a time. Is there any Mobile or Win8 App or any other way to do Multiple (Say 25) Peripheral Simulation simultaneously?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.